# How to get the token after using AspNet.Security.OAuth.Spotify?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth, asp.net-identity, spotify

I have an ASP.NET MVC web app and am using the authenticator with Microsoft Identity to create an account by logging in to Spotify. However, it seems I am unable to get the access token after doing so, I've tried a few different ways which have either not returned the token or I've gotten null.

Here's my `Program.cs` code, which does at very least get me to the Spotify login in page and redirect me back to my site:

```
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
builder.Services.AddSingleton(SpotifyClientConfig.CreateDefault());

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("Spotify", policy =>
    {
        policy.AuthenticationSchemes.Add("Spotify");
        policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
    });
});
builder.Services
  .AddAuthentication(options =>
  {
      options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
  })
  .AddCookie(options =>
  {
      options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
  })
  .AddSpotify(options =>
  {
      options.ClientId = "client";
      options.ClientSecret = "secret";
      options.CallbackPath = "/callback";
      options.SaveTokens = true;

      var scopes = new List<string> {
            UserReadEmail, UserReadPrivate, PlaylistReadPrivate, PlaylistReadCollaborative
      };
      options.Scope.Add(string.Join(",", scopes));
  });

builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
        .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
        {
            options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/", "Spotify");
        });
```

And here's where I'm trying to get the token in my home controller:

```
    public async  Task<IActionResult> StoreMusic()
    {
        TryUpdateModelAsync(logModel);
        long unixTimeMilliseconds = new DateTimeOffset(logModel.Time.ToUniversalTime()).ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
        var spotify = await BuildClient();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    public async Task<SpotifyClient> BuildClient()
    {
        var token = await _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("Spotify", "access_token");
        return new SpotifyClient(_spotifyClientConfig.WithToken(token));
    }
```

This crashes the page as the token is null. No idea where to go from here, the code is very similar to examples I've seen.